# Can I relation multiple 'where' condition in pg-promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I using pg-promise with express 4 on node 8.2.0.
Inside that I want to concatenate *`where` condition*.

But, I couldn't find that way. Please help me.

### I expect this.

```
let ids = [10, 20, 30]
db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {something-way}', ids)
```

=> I expect to execute query like a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 10 & id = 20 & id = 30;`

### Question

Can I make query like it with pg-promise's methods?
Or I must concatenate string?

Please lend me your wisdom.

Comment: Are you trying to check if `id` is among the values specified?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logic of your `WHERE` clause.

If the logic is to select all records where `id` is one of the values, then you can use `:csv` modifier supported by [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), in combination with the `WHERE IN` clause:

```
const ids = [10, 20, 30];
db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1:csv)', [ids]);
```

And if it is something else, then again, it depends on the logic, which you would need to clarify in your question.